# Responsive absolute image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have been searching for a while now, but cannot find anything that is exactly what I need. I am currently working on my first site and need help. I am trying to create a grid of images that are positioned absolute, but are also responsive to different size monitors as it is an intranet solution.

HTML:

```
<a href="google.com">
    <img src="M.png" alt="A" class="image2" align="left" style=";">
</a>

<a href="google.com/">
    <img src="kjsa.jpg" alt="C" class="image3" align="left" style="max-width:100%;">
</a>

<a href="google.com">
    <img src="/example.png" alt="b" class="image4" align="left" style="max-width:100%;">
</a>

<a href="google.com">
    <img src="exmple.png" alt="C" class="image5" align="left" style="max-width:100%;">
</a>

<a href="google.com">
    <img src="example.png" alt="e" class="image6" align="left" style="max-width:100%;">
</a>

<a href="google.com">
    <img src="example.png" alt="e" class="image7" align="left" style="max-width:100%;">
</a>
```

CSS:

```
img.image2 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 33.15%;
    max-width: 100%; 
}

img.image3 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 44.21%;
    max-width: 100%; 
}

img.image4 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 55.26%;
    max-width: 100%; 
}
img.image5 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 33.15%;
    top: 400px;
    max-width: 100%; 
}

img.image6 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 44.21%;
    top: 400px; 
    max-width: 100%; 
}

img.image7 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 55.26%;
    top: 400px;
    max-width: 100%; 
}
```

In essence, I need the pictures to retain the same position in relation to the screen and browser size, but I need them to be able to resize depending on monitor resolution.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Give [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) a look. It is _excellent_ for responsive page design and easy to learn. It will save you lots of time with what you are trying to do.

Comment: Get rid of all those absolute positionings and just use flexbox. Your images and the box itself will be responsive.

Answer (score 1):

why you are useing position absolute ?!!!!
if you want to have GRID layout and responsive design you can have same code like : 
HTML :

```
    <div class="col">
      <a href="google.com">
        <img src="example.png" class="img">
      </a>
   </div>
    <div class="col">
      <a href="google.com">
        <img src="example.png" class="img">
      </a>
   </div>
```

CSS : (if you have 5 column => width: 100/5 = 17%)

```
* , *::after , *::before{
   box-sizing : border-box;
}
.col{
    width    : 17%;
    margin   : 0 1%;
    overflow : hidden;
    float    : left;
}
 a{
     display : inline-block;
 }
.img{
   width     : 100%;
   height    : auto;
   max-width : 100%;
}
```

After that if you want to set for other device you can use the MEDIA Query :

```
@media screen and (min-width: 62em) { /** 1em = 16px **/
    .col{
      width : 45%;   
      .....
    }
    .....
}
```